# ActiveX : How to change implementation from Qt to wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, activex

I was using QAxWidget to access an ActiveX control. I am trying to move to wxActiveXContainer. My initial Qt code was quite simple in syntax. I am struggling to obtain something somewhat equivalent with wxWidgets. I have gone through excel and pdf example. I am still unable to connect to the ActiveX with wxActiveXContainer. I am coding in C++ on VS2019.

Here is my initial Qt code. The str output contained everything I needed to complete my needs.

```
#include "sc_samlight_client_ctrl_type_lib.h"
    QAxWidget actX(this);
    actX.setVisible(false);
    actX.setControl(QUuid(__uuidof(ScSamlightClientCtrl)).toString());

    QString str = actX.generateDocumentation();
```

Here is what I have started for wxWidgets

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "wx/msw/ole/activex.h"
#include "wx/msw/ole/automtn.h" 
#include "sc_samlight_client_ctrl_type_lib.h"

    wxWindow* parent; // from caller...

// This seems to connect to something...
    wxAutomationObject ao;
    ao.CreateInstance(wxS("SCAPS.ScSamlightClientCtrl"));

// This does not work... I realy don't know what to pass as third argument. I am not even sure about the second one...
    wxActiveXContainer* m_pAX;
    m_pAX = new wxActiveXContainer(parent, __uuidof(ScSamlightClientCtrl), NULL);
```

The "sc_samlight_client_ctrl_type_lib.h" is the interface given with the equipement/program I want to control.

The real question is : for any ActiveX, using wxWidgets, how can I connect to it and obtain its interface documentation.

Comment: @MHeleneLavole, what kind of ActiveX do you have? Custom one? Or some Word/Excel/Access one?

Comment: @Igor, The ActiveX is from SCAPS (https://scaps.com) and is working fine since many years to control scanner and laser systems. It connects fine with c# on visual studio (they have examples).

Answer (score 0):

`wxActiveXContainer` is for embedding an ActiveX window inside wxWidgets application and I am not sure you need it at all here.

Have you tried just using `ao.CallMethod("generateDocumentation")`?

Comment: Your probably right about not needing wxActiveContainer. However, the generateDocumentation is from Qt, not my component... so it is obviously not working.

Comment: I have tried CallMethod("ScIsRunning") which is the most basic function but I get the error "OLE Automation error in ScIsRunning: Unknown error 8000fff"

Comment: Here is the public method given :
virtual /* [id] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ScIsRunning( 
            /* [retval][out] */ long *res) = 0;